# Android progressive media playback on a real device - MediaPlayer.prepare() taking forever

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a playlist with songs and their urls
When i try to do following:

```
mp.setDataSource(getCurrentSong().getUrl());
mp.prepareASync();
```

It works like a charm on the emulator, but when I try and run it on a real device (Acer Liquid Mini) it just gets stuck on preparing, `onPrepared()` never gets called, and I get an Info in my `onInfo()` giving me what = 1, extra = 44; so I tried calling

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(getCurrentSong.getUrl());
mp.prepareASync();
```

But it doesn't help, It still never calls onPrepared(), and always giving me the same what = 1, extra = 44 Info.
Is there any list of MediaPlayer onInfo/onError codes? How can I solve this?
And yeah, I'm running my app on 2.2, for both emulator and a real device.

Comment: I think that `what = 1` is for `MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN`

Comment: What happens if you do it with `mp.prepare()` ? Does it finish at some point?

Comment: yeah, it did finish, and I shouldn't been resetting the player, thanks for pointing that out mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just found out that Info(1,44) and Info(1,26) don't mean I have errors, and I shouldn't have reseted the player. Now everything goes just fine.
Here's the complete list of Info's from android source: https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h